# OpenGl, C#, Tao. Color of drawing stays always the same

Tags: c#, opengl, colors, tao-framework

Using SimpleOpenGLControl Component in Windows Forms,
I'm trying to draw a line, for example. Or any other untextured thing. 
Using glcolor3b, 3ub, 3d, 3f functions, their analogs with 4 parameters - and nothing happens. Color stays the same, and I can't manage what will be this color. In one project it is like green, in other like light grey.
Now I know that trouble lies in my Background class, in method LoadTextureForModel:

```
public class Background : Visible
        {
            public Background(string Path)
            {
                LoadTextureForModel(Path);
            }
            public override void Display()
            {
                MyGlutUser.DrawRect((int)TextureObj(), new FPoint(0, 0),
                                    MyGlutUser.WorldW + 100, MyGlutUser.WorldH + 100);
            }
        }
public abstract class Visible
        {
            public abstract void Display();
            public String PathToImage
            { get; set; }
            public RGBubColor Color
            { get; set; }
            protected int imageID;
            public int ImageID
            {
                get
                {
                    return imageID;
                }
                set
                {
                    imageID = value;
                }
            }
            protected int mGlTextureObject { get; set; }
            public FPoint Location
            { get; set; }
            public static int Counter = 0;
            public int TextureObj()
            {
                return mGlTextureObject;
            }
            public void LoadTextureForModel(string FileName)
            {
                PathToImage = FileName;
                Il.ilGenImages(1, out imageID);
                Il.ilBindImage(imageID);
                if (Il.ilLoadImage(PathToImage))
                {
                    int width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
                    int height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT); 
                    int bitspp = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_BITS_PER_PIXEL);

                    switch (bitspp) // в зависимости оп полученного результата 
                    {
                        case 24:
                            mGlTextureObject = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGB, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                            break;
                        case 32:
                            mGlTextureObject = MakeGlTexture(Gl.GL_RGBA, Il.ilGetData(), width, height);
                            break;

                    }

                    Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref imageID);
                }

            }
```

Code for drawing the line:

```
public static void DrawLine(FPoint p1, FPoint p2)
            {
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES);
                Gl.glVertex2d(p1.x, p1.y);
                Gl.glVertex2d(p2.x, p2.y);
                Gl.glEnd();

            }
public static void DrawLine(RGBubColor Color, FPoint p1, FPoint p2)
            {
                Gl.glColor3d((double)Color.r / 255.0, (double)Color.g / 255.0, (double)Color.b / 255.0);
                DrawLine(p1, p2);
            }
public struct RGBubColor
        {
            public byte r; public byte g; public byte b;
            public RGBubColor(byte r, byte g, byte b)
            {
                this.r = r;
                this.g = g;
                this.b = b;
            }
        };
```

Invokation:

```
GlutUser.DrawLine(new RGBubColor(127, 0, 0), 5, new FPoint(0, 0), new FPoint(500, 500));
```

I need a way to fix my LoadTextureForModel function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code to clean color & matrix state:

```
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glTranslated(a, b, c);
        Gl.glScaled(zoom, zoom, zoom);

            ---------------
              drawing code
            ---------------

        Gl.glPopMatrix();
        Gl.glFlush();
```

and

```
        Gl.glClearColor(clearR / 255f, clearG / 255f, clearB / 255f, 1);
```

It works good for me

**EDIT**

There is worked code below which fix your bug I think.

**[EXAMPLE:](http://esate.ru/page/osnovy-vizualizatsii-2D-primitivov-openGL)**

```
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(255, 0, 0);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINE_LOOP);

            Gl.glVertex2d(8, 7);
            Gl.glVertex2d(15, 27);
            Gl.glVertex2d(17, 27);
            Gl.glVertex2d(23, 7);
            Gl.glVertex2d(21, 7);
            Gl.glVertex2d(19, 14);
            Gl.glVertex2d(12.5, 14);
            Gl.glVertex2d(10, 7);

        Gl.glEnd();

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINE_LOOP);

            Gl.glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
            Gl.glVertex2d(18.5, 16);
            Gl.glVertex2d(16, 25);
            Gl.glVertex2d(13.2, 16);

        Gl.glEnd();

        Gl.glFlush();
```

(Full version of the code you'll find [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63841209/TaoFramework_change_line_color.cs))

And you'll get something like [image: this]

Comment: That introduces a stack overflow after a few frames. If it is a projection matrix, then GL only guarantees a stack depth of 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I used this part of code by timer tick and all works fine for me.

Comment: Then your OpenGL implementation is buggy. Since you are not popping your matrix anywhere, you will overflow it very quickly.

Comment: what arguments should I send into Translated and Scaled?

Comment: it's functions for transforming and zooming. You could don't use it if you don't need it :)

Comment: Thanks i tried to do this, still there are problems. See new addition to my question...

Comment: There is a very good tutorial by Tao Framework step by step (if you familiar with russian): http://esate.ru/page/osnovy-vizualizatsii-2D-primitivov-openGL

Comment: If you don't, I will be there tomorrow (it's 01:00 AM now in my region, sorry)

Comment: Я русский :) Я с того сайта все и копировал, но видишь ли что делается тем не менее
И у меня 3 часа ночи, так что понимаю)

Comment: thank you, that didn't solve problem, but I know more about problem's source now, see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why your edit doesn't work correctly:

You should only call

```
Gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

once per run through your loop, unless you explicitly want to reset your colors or your view matrix (you shouldn't need to in most cases).

The same goes for

```
Gl.glFlush();
```

which generally only needs to be called at the end of your main drawing loop.

This means your DrawLines function should look something like:

```
    public static void DrawLine(FPoint p1, FPoint p2)
    {
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES);
        Gl.glVertex2d(p1.x, p1.y);
        Gl.glVertex2d(p2.x, p2.y);
        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

And your main loop should look something like:

```
//Loop Start
GL.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GL.glLoadIdentity();

//Tranformation code here.

Gl.glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
DrawLine(p1,p2);

//Any other drawing code.

Gl.glFlush();
//End Loop
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thank you, that didn't solve problem, but I know more about problem's source now, see edited question.